# Access virtualbox VMs as root

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualbox, privileges

I have VMs created as normal user. I can access them via the GUI and via python bindings (pyvbox). I have a python script that I need to run as root to access other ressources. I cannot access any VMs via the GUI nor python bindings as root. How can I access them from my script ?

Should I drop privileges from my script ran as root whenever I need to access vbox ? and then go back to root user when i need to access other resources ? How would you do this and is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that requires the name of the user for which you want to monitor VMs:

```
import os, pwd, virtualbox

vbox_user="my_user"
pw=pwd.getpwnam(vbox_user)
root_uid=os.getuid()

# change location of vbox settings file
os.environ["XDG_CONFIG_HOME"]="/home/{}/.config".format(vbox_user)

# change uid to user's
# setting euid alone does not work
os.setresuid(pw.pw_uid, pw.pw_uid, uid)

# create your vbox 
vbox=virtualbox.VirtualBox()

# change back to initial uid
os.setresuid(uid, uid, uid)
```

You can use vbox exactly like you would as vbox_user.